# Get value from input with currency mask in Angular2

Tags: jquery, angular

I used [maskMoney](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/) jquery plugin on the input inside a form. when I wanna get data from those input field it's empty!

**Here is my MaskMoney directive:**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";
declare var $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[money]'
})
export class CurrencyMaskDirective {
  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
    let native = el.nativeElement;
    $(native).maskMoney({
      suffix: " $",
      thousands: '،',
      decimal: '',
      precision: 3,
      affixesStay: false
    });
  }
}
```

**Here is my form:**

```
<form role="form" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addcharge(f)" novalidate>
   <input type="text" name="value" #value="ngModel" ngModel money>
</form>

// in ts file
addcharge(g) {
   console.log(g.value);
}
```

When I log the value is empty in console! how can I get value from that input properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You donot need a form for a single input i feel this should work fine

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="value" #titleInput money>
  <button type="submit" (click) = 'addTodo(titleInput.value)'>Add</button>
</div>


  addTodo(title:string) {
    console.log(title);
  }
```

If you need to look into Reactive or Template Driven Forms you can look @ this page for examples

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/reactive

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/template

update

Check this Plunker link

https://plnkr.co/edit/oicEbx5HQj3T208GCuU7?p=preview

Comment: I added only one of the input in this question, I have alot more input in the main form.

Comment: Please look at the links the code is also available you can check the repo link on that

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to assign ngModel in html view like below code.

```
<form role="form" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addcharge(f)" novalidate>
   <input type="text" name="value" #value="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="moneyValue" money>
</form>

// in ts file
moneyValue: string = null;
addcharge(g) {
   console.log(this.moneyValue);
}
```

Comment: are you trying to log `this.moneyValue` ?